# What's all the hype over objectsets in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0

I am an intermediate user of EF in .net 3.5 and have recently moved to working with .net 4.

One thing i keep coming across when reading various tutorials is the use of ObjectSets instead of ObjectQuerys and that they are a great new feature.

What is so great about them?

Please enlighten me.

Kind regards,
Kohan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you mean in your question, but what's really cool about ObjectSet is that it implements an interface **IObjectSet** which means you can fake it very easily and **test the code** down until the data access layer.

What's even cooler, is that since the ObjectSet use generic types (**IObjectSet< T >**), you can have a generic repository and implement the **Unit Of Work** pattern.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
     IQueryable<T> GetQuery();
     IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
     IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> where);
     T Single(Func<T, bool> where);
     T First(Func<T, bool> where);

     void Delete(T entity);
     void Add(T entity);
     void Attach(T entity);
     void SaveChanges();
}
```

complete article here :

http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/

Comment: Okay that makes sence since i was looking at tutorials on making a generic repository when i saw this "hype". Cheers.

Comment: Just out of interest and i will make a new question if needed but whats the difference between adding a Product through an objectquery, objectset, or on the objectcontext like i have shown above?

Comment: I actually don't know the answer to that question :-/
My first guess is that it has something to do with self-tracking entities vs Persistence agnostic entities when using POCO. But not so sure about that, sorry.

Comment: No probs. Thanks for the help i have added a new question for this and edited the question here for clarity sake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810988/3-methods-for-adding-a-product-through-entity-framework-whats-the-difference